# C# WPF Datagrid crear drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy aprendiendo WPF con Visual Studio 2022, y quiero dominar el uso del control Datagrid y me gustaría me indicaran un enlace o sitio donde haya un buen ejemplo o tutorial para hacer drag & drop con las filas. Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos a todos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por el momento no estoy preguntando un problema en específico a resolver, más bien, por lo que soy nuevo en WPF, estoy solicitando me indicaran un enlace, un sitio donde pueda estudiar un demo de cómo implementar el arrastrar y soltar con el control Datagrid. Gracias a todos del foro.

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes usar son los ejemplos de la documentacion de windows

Comment: Lo que estoy buscando es, la gente que tiene experiencia en WPF, me indique los enlaces o los sitios con ejemplos correctos para documentarme. He buscado en Google, pero hay muchos ejemplos muy incompletos y se pierde mucho tiempo. Gracias rexxarcat por tu ayuda, pero si me indicaras un buen ejemplo con datagrid te lo agradecería mucho.